# Xuggler: deep copy of an IContainer

Tags: java, deep-copy, xuggler

I have the code:

```
IContainer container = ...;
IContainer copy = container;
```

But I think, it doesn't make a deep copy of this IContainer.

Does somebody know how to make a deep copy of an IContainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create new container, similar to original one, and then copy from one to another by `IPacket` as if you do normal read/write.

Comment: I think not. `Xuggler` is a wrapper around `ffmpeg`. Cloning container means copying it to some destination .